# Does overloading the new operator in C++ redefine the operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

When overloading the new operator in a global scope in C++, are we just redefining the original functionality? From what I understand operator and function overloading works when the overloads have different signatures, however when overloading new operator using

```
void* operator new(size_t n){
    return malloc(n);
}
```

we change the underlying functionality itself and whenever we call new this new overload is called? Does this not violate the idea of overloads having different and unique signatures?

I tried overloading the new array operator with extra parameters and how that works is consistent with my current understanding of operator/function overloads. However overloading the new operator and new array operator with just one parameter is where I'm confused.

Comment: Overloading is defining multiple function with the same name but different arguments. If you define a function (operator or not) without changing the arguments it's not an overload, it's a redefinition and that's not allowed.

Comment: This is not the `new` operator; it’s the function named `operator new`. When you write `new X;` the `new` operator calls `operator new` to allocate memory, then constructs an object of type `X` in the newly allocated space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[operator new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) is *replacable* (from cppreference, same link):

> The versions (1-4) are implicitly declared in each translation unit even if the  header is not included. Versions (1-8) are replaceable: a user-provided non-member function with the same signature defined anywhere in the program, in any source file, replaces the default version. Its declaration does not need to be visible.

This is not the usual function overloading. You cannot overload a function with same signature. Overloads must be distinguishable by their arguments. Nevertheless, colloquially one often talks about "overloading the new operator" which is ok in the wider sense of "overloading", but in strict c++ terminology not right.